# Difference between enterLocal...() and enterRemote...() methods in FTPClient class from org.apache.commons.net.ftp

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons-net

I'm trying to figure out the difference between `enterLocalActiveMode()`/`enterLocalPassiveMode()` and `enterRemoteActiveMode(InetAddress host, int port)`/`enterRemotePassiveMode()` methods of [`FTPClient` class from org.apache.commons.net.ftp](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html).

I've only found some information about the difference between active and passive mode with FTP. But I don't understand the concept of local and remote previously mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Apache Commons Net documentation (which you link yourself in the question) covers this.

In 99.9% cases, you want to use `FTPClient.enterLocal*Mode`. That's for *client-server* transfers.

The `FTPClient.enterRemote*Mode` is only for *server-server* transfers (aka [FXP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_eXchange_Protocol)). What most FTP servers do not allow anyway.